# How to ignore some migrations in production

Tags: django, database, django-migrations

By mistake, now there is an inconsistency in the production and my local Django Migrations and the `makemigrations` command will generate correct migrations that when I locally run with an empty database. for example, this migration will generate:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('campaign', '0208_auto_20190619_0929'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='bannerad',
            name='average_price',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='bannerad',
            name='click',
        ),
        .... blah
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='bannerad',
            name='size',
            field=models.IntegerField(choices=[(0, '120x240'), (1, '120x600'), (2, '970x250'), (3, '160x600'), (4, '240x240'), (5, '300x100'), (6, '300x250'), (7, '468x60'), (8, '600x300'), (9, '728x90')]),
        ),
    ]
```

but in the production running the generated migrations already migrated (for example the Bannerad model in production database has not `average_price`)
and when I run the `migrate` command in production. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you mean production has ran a migration and you're going to remove it from the project? If so, just delete that migration record from the production db.

Comment: @markwalker_ Yes i have removed a migrated file by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark a migration as already applied with the [`--fake`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) parameter

E.g. to fake every unapplied migration up to and including `0209`:

`manage.py migrate --fake campaign 0209`

Note that you can only fake the complete migrations, not individual operations within a migration.